# File Check Loop and Repeat on self contained PS

Tags: powershell, loops, if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements

I have a working code in PS. But I'm a complete Noob with just days of experience. Running the code pulls an RSS feed; save as XML; parsed XML; renamed from the title fetch from the parse and File check that I'm using to trigger a python to start an LED on a Raspberry pi. Works (100%)

I don't know how to clean my code; or make it loop. I need to keep executing until The RSS Feed change back to default.

I built the code from chunks of this community can someone help please

```
# Get Atom Feed
$Response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://alerts.weather.gov/cap/wwaatmget.php?x=FLC001&amp;y=0" -UseBasicParsing -ContentType "application/xml" -OutFile "C:\saveA.xml"
If ($Response.StatusCode -ne "200") {
    # Feed failed to respond.
    Write-Host "Message: $($Response.StatusCode) $($Response.StatusDescription)"
}

## Delegates the Save File as saveA.xml
$path = 'C:\saveA.xml'
## Prevents repeated copies of ("In_Alachua_$($OutputFileName).xml") = saveB.xml
Remove-Item -Path 'C:\saveB.xml' 
## RSS File in XML
$Data = Get-Content C:\saveA.xml
## RSS File Translate to XML for parse
[xml]$Data=Get-Content C:\saveA.xml
$InputFileNAme = $path
$OutputFileName = $Data.feed.entry.title 
## Rename the $OutputFileName to "In_Alachua_$($OutputFileName).xml" = In_Alachua_saveB.xml
Rename-Item -Path $InputFileNAme -Force -NewName  ("In_Alachua_$($OutputFileName).xml")

## file Check specific
Test-Path -Path "C:\saveB.xml" -PathType Leaf

# Full path of the Default file
$file = 'In_Alachua_saveB.xml'

# If the file does not exist, Starts LED Trigger GPI ON
if (-not(Test-Path -Path $file -PathType Leaf)) {
    try {
        Start-Process C:\Remote_Pi_Trigger.py
            }
    catch {
        throw $_.Exception.Message 
    }
}
# If the file already exists, Start LED Trigger GPI Default.
else {
    Start-Process C:\Remote_Pi_Trigger_Clean.py
}
```

Comment: What makes you think the script requires "cleaning"? Variable naming appears reasonable, control flow layout makes sense - and it's working :)

Comment: If you want to follow some high level PS best practices, then you can go through [THIS](https://www.scriptrunner.com/en/blog/5-powershell-scripting-best-practices/)

Comment: Thank you; I really need a 3 step loop so when is trigger ON don't repeat the process but keep checking until trigger is OFF.